# Oracle - How to order then distinct rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to order records first, then distinct them (distinct PersonID but by getting the entire row content without duplicate PersonID ) Using a single query on oracle.

In the example:sort by RecordType (p first) then get distinct PersonID list

desired result for case 1:

```
(1,'John', 'Doe', 2,'P' );
(2,'Scot', 'Mic', 1,'P' );
```

desired result for case 2:

```
(1,'John', 'Doe', 1,'S' );  
(2,'Scot', 'Mic', 1,'P' )
```

Sql:

```
drop table test_records;

CREATE TABLE test_records
(
  PersonID int,
  LastName varchar(255),
  FirstName varchar(255),
  RecordId int,
  RecordType varchar(255)

); 

1 case:
insert into test_records values(1,'John', 'Doe', 1,'S' );  
insert into test_records values(1,'John', 'Doe', 2,'P' );
insert into test_records values(1,'John', 'Doe', 3,'S' );
insert into test_records values(1,'John', 'Doe', 4,'S' );
insert into test_records values(1,'John', 'Doe', 1,'S' );
insert into test_records values(2,'Scot', 'Mic', 1,'P' );


2 case:
insert into test_records values(1,'John', 'Doe', 1,'S' );  
insert into test_records values(1,'John', 'Doe', 2,'S' );
insert into test_records values(1,'John', 'Doe', 3,'S' );
insert into test_records values(1,'John', 'Doe', 4,'S' );
insert into test_records values(1,'John', 'Doe', 1,'S' );
insert into test_records values(2,'Scot', 'Mic', 1,'P' );
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? THe question is currently tagged with [tag:oracle], but also with [tag:tsql], which suggests MS SQL Server or Sybase.

Comment: If you are using Oracle (as specified in the text), you should use `varchar2()` rather than `varchar()`.  I'm removing the `tsql` tag because that is not (typically) used with Oracle databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an analytic `row_number()` call is what you're looking for

```
SELECT PersonID, LastName, FirstName, RecordId, RecordType
FROM   (SELECT PersonID, LastName, FirstName, RecordId, RecordType,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY RecordType ASC) AS rn
        FROM   test_records) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```