# Oracle Cost of analytic function vs double fetch

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to eliminate duplicate rows from my select by person ID [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23159801/oracle-how-to-order-then-distinct-rows/23159983#23159983) 

 I got a solution using Analytic function:

```
SELECT PersonID, LastName, FirstName, RecordId, RecordType
FROM   (SELECT PersonID, LastName, FirstName, RecordId, RecordType,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY RecordType ASC) AS rn
        FROM   test_records) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

I would like to understand if it will be more expensive using this Analytic function then  just running two consecutive query's :

```
  SELECT distinct PersonID from test_records;
```

Then for each PersonID (java code or plsql):

```
  SELECT * from test_records where PersonID =X and rownum = 1;
```

Will it be correct comparing the explain plan and the cost?

Will it be correct to add the costs of the two querys and compare to the Analytic function cost?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of general rules to be mindful of:

1. Prefer using the builtin functions for analytics. Since they're native, the CBO can do a lot of behind-the-scenes magic to speed things up.
2. Avoid making multiple queries if you can. The overhead of sending the query from your application will really start to add up and cause a lot of performance issues. If you're doing it in PL/SQL, the penalty is reduced, but it's still less efficient than a single query.

Based on what you've posted, I would recommend you use the analytic function. However, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish in this query, but it doesn't look like either approach is going to be very good. I don't know if this is possible, but you might want to change up your schema if you can.

It seems like you're storing the data in a really nasty way. [From your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23159801/oracle-how-to-order-then-distinct-rows/23159983#23159983), it looks like you don't have a way to put a good index on the table. No indexing combined with these analytic functions will *dramatically* reduce the scalability of that table. If you put a few thousand rows in there, you're going to be seeing some awfully long-running queries.

Comment: >> storing the data in a really nasty 
- yes I know, this is the way I need to handle it.. I get a view of events (event id and person id ) and i need to process the distinct persons (person could be in few events)

Comment: Will it be correct to add the costs of the two query's and compare to the Analytic function cost?

Comment: If the PersonID value is unique to each user (1 => John Doe) then you can get the distinct PersonID,  last name,  and first name by simply using the DISTINCT keyword and omitting the last two column from your SELECT statement. What specific information do you need from this query?

Answer (score 2):

The right answer is to try both methods and compare them in your environment.  I do note that the two methods do not produce the same results.  The first query gives the "first" `RecordType`.  The second gives an arbitrary row (and I'm assuming `row_num` should really be `rownum`.

Each has benefits.  From the perspective of SQL only, the second method will use fewer Oracle resources.  Alas, this will (I almost 100% sure) be overcome by the expense of running lots and lots of queries.  Don't forget the looping logic and all the rest as well.

Why is the first method better?  First, it is only one query so it incurs overhead of running a query only once.  Second, it doesn't require a lot of extra non-SQL code for looping and so on.  Third, the query can run in parallel.  Fourth, Oracle analytic functions are usually pretty fast.

There might be some cases where the second method is better.  For instance, if you have 1,000,000 records and only one person, then the second will definitely be faster.  So, it is not a slam-dunk as to which is better.  But for most distributions of data, I'd go with the first method.